# How to return sql query result messages with c# ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried following code but I couldn't find success messages from it.Here `commandText` can be insert,update,delete or select query and I need dataset if it is a select query else success messages like in sql result `output("12 row(s) inserted successfully")`.I can't use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteNonQuery` methods since I need dataset output when select query executed.

```
public static  DataSet ExecuteDataset(string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageInfo += "\n" + e.Message;
            };
            cn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, cn))
            {

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dt); // Do something with DataTable
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have seen a lot of questions about this but it seems the only real option is to implement the messages yourself. Problem being you wont have the actual message generated from the database.

Comment: yep.i checked that eventhandler didn't call except at first time.And MessageInfo is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by following way but hope there should be a better way.

```
 string type = Query.Trim().Split(' ')[0].ToLower();
    if ( type == "select")
    {
        DataSet result = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.Text, Query);                

    }
    else
    {                
        if(type == "insert") type="inserted."; else type=type+"d.";
        int a=(int)SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, Query);
        if (a > 0)
        {
            lblInfo.Text = "Query executed successfully. " + a.ToString() + " row(s) " + type;                

        }
    }
```

I found another one.That's better than above one.

```
query = resultQuery + "  SELECT '('+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@ROWCOUNT)+' row(s) affected)' AS RESULT";
DataSet result = DataSet result = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.Text, query);

        if (result.DefaultViewManager.DataViewSettingCollectionString.Contains("Table") == true)
        {
            sqlGrid.Visible = true;
            sqlGrid.DataSource = result;
            sqlGrid.DataBind();
        }
        if (sqlGrid.Rows.Count==1 && sqlGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Count==1)
        {
            string text = (sqlGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Text;
            if (text.Contains("row(s) affected"))
            {
                lblInfo.Text=text;
                lblInfo.Visible=true;
                sqlGrid.DataSource = null;
                sqlGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using System.Data version 4.0.0.0 and the following works for me with UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE and SELECT statements.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    var rowsAffected = -1;

    adapter.SelectCommand.StatementCompleted += delegate (object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        rowsAffected = e.RecordCount;
    };

    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dt); // Do something with DataTable
    return dt;
}
```